# intellij reset proxy setting without starting the application / License server connection failed

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-2020

Recently while tryig to setup Mavne, I accidently setup a proxy settings which was not correct.
Next time, when I started the intelliJ idea, it failed to connect to the license server. I immediately realized that this issue occured due to incorrect proxy setting applied last time.

IntelliJ idea do not allow you to access application if license is not renewed using the license server.

How to reset the proxy server settings without application already running?
Please note that the idea version is 2020.3 on Windows 10 and I do not have access to application GUI.

Answer (score 3):

All I needed to correct proxy settings server URL to get through license server. Other may have requiremnt to set it to "No proxy".

In order to accomplish that you need to ascertain "idea.config.path".

For IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3, the different paths are:

**Windows:**

```
Configuration (idea.config.path): C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\plugins
System (idea.system.path): C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3
Logs (idea.log.path): C:\Users\<USER_NAME>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\log
```

**macOS:**

```
Configuration (idea.config.path): <USER_HOME>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): <USER_HOME>/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/plugins
System (idea.system.path): <USER_HOME>/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3
Logs (idea.log.path): <USER_HOME>/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3
```

**Linux:**

```
Configuration (idea.config.path): <USER_HOME>/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3
Plugins (idea.plugins.path): <USER_HOME>/.local/share/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3
System (idea.system.path): <USER_HOME>/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3
Logs (idea.log.path): <USER_HOME>/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.3/log
```

- Go to the `idea.config.path\options` and edit proxy.settings to change settings.

[image]

- If you want to set the idea settings to "No proxy", simply delete the `proxy.settings` file.
- For intellij version 2019.3 and below, the default directories in wondows and linux are different:

> Windows: %HOMEPATH%\.\config
>
> Example - C:\Users\JohnS.IntelliJIdea2019.3\config
>
> Linux: <USER_HOME>/./config
>
> Example - <USER_HOME>/.IntelliJIdea2019.3/config